# Pandas: Issue at dropping undesirable zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to drop two last zeros at the hours column

```
01/05/2023;0000;
01/05/2023;0100;
01/05/2023;0200;
01/05/2023;0300;
01/05/2023;0400;
01/05/2023;0500;
01/05/2023;0600;
01/05/2023;0700;
```

and so on.

I tried the `df= df[df[1] != 00]`, but got no success.
Is there any other alternative for this?

The column must be like that:

```
01/05/2023;00;
01/05/2023;01;
01/05/2023;02;
01/05/2023;03;
01/05/2023;04;
01/05/2023;05;
01/05/2023;06;
01/05/2023;07;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark DataFrame

Comment: To clarify: the dataframe has dtypes for each column. What's the value of `df.dtypes` ?

Comment: @NickODell sorry. It's a non-null integer (int64)

Comment: Huh? The field has leading zeros in it. It couldn't be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the column type is string. if yes, you can apply slicing on that column.

```
df['colName'] = df['colName'].str[0:2]
```

if it is not a string type, we can convert it to string and then apply

```
df['colName'] = df['colName'].astype(str).str[0:2]
```

Comment: thanks, but I just note that it's an integer

Comment: just updated the code. You can try that.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file (or buffer, demonstrated below) and keep the types string.  Then you can modify the column as presented:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

buffer = io.StringIO('''\
01/05/2023;0000;
01/05/2023;0100;
01/05/2023;0200;
01/05/2023;0300;
01/05/2023;0400;
01/05/2023;0500;
01/05/2023;0600;
01/05/2023;0700;
''')

df = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=';', header=None, dtype=str)  # read columns as str
df[1] = df[1].str[:2]  # select the first two characters of column 1
buffer2 = df.to_csv(None, sep=';', header=None, index=False)
print(buffer2)
```

Output:

```
01/05/2023;00;
01/05/2023;01;
01/05/2023;02;
01/05/2023;03;
01/05/2023;04;
01/05/2023;05;
01/05/2023;06;
01/05/2023;07;
```